# Commas before and after "therefore" but not before and after "also"

Tags: commas, adverbs

Consider the following sentences:

> The shirt is pink and is, therefore, very stylish.
>
> The shirt is pink and is also very stylish.

In the first sentence, I feel as though I need to use commas around the word "***therefore***." However, I don't feel the need to use commas around "***also***" in the second sentence. This is strange to me because it seems that the two words are acting as the same part of speech in each sentence.

Is the punctuation in one of these sentences incorrect? Is there some subtle difference between the words "***therefore***" and "***also***" that explains why commas could be warranted in the first sentence but not in the second?

Comment: I'd say that the two sentences are different in form: the first is showing causation, while the second is giving two separate facts. In the second sentence, "also" is modifying "is"; while in the first "therefore" is modifying "(the shirt) is very stylish".

Comment: Since commas are optional around either word, your question boils down to why you personally "feel" as you do about them. On that, you are more expert than any of us.

Comment: It's a stylistic choice. One factor you might be encountering is syllable length; perhaps you associate "therefore" with a greater pause because it takes a little longer to say and, thus, introduce commas. As my last sentence shows, this comma convention isn't a strict rule, and other factors like register and personal preference come into play.

Comment: Note that 'thus' in place of 'therefore' would sound very odd with the comma-pauses. But they are otherwise interchangeable. The commas are optional around 'therefore' in this sentence (you can choose the staccato parenthetical version or the smooth-running version). But this _is_ largely style. Note also that 'Too, we always use a comma after sentence-initial "too" ' sounds generally acceptable in the US but not in the UK.

Comment: What @StuartF said. Because ***therefore*** here is effectively a "sentence" conjunctive adverb (AND perhaps because it's "longer" than alternatives such as ***thus, hence***), it's easier for the reader / audience if you separate it out more distinctively with commas / pauses. But as Edwin says, it's essentially a stylistic choice.